# Create a while loop to open directory and read the information inside

Tags: php

How can I create a while loop to open a directory, read different directories and grab the images that I have inside the directories

I have this but it doesn't work

$TPL['directory']= array();

```
$FP = opendir($PHOTOS_PATH);
while(false !== ($DIR = readdir($FP))){

    if ($DIR == "." || $DIR == "..") continue;
    $TPL['directory'][]= $DIR;
}
closedir($FP);
```

Comment: To be the bearer of a strictly correct, but unhelpful comment: With code.

Comment: while loops can't open directories. If you need to find certain files in a directory there are plenty of ways, one might be the use of `glob()`, another the usage of the symfony/finder package, yet another `scandir()` used recursively. Additionally you may try the DirectoryIterator… And I am pretty sure, there are more ways to do that.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. What specifically goes wrong? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick. I haven't tested the code though

```
// location of directory
$directoryPath = 'DIRECTORY_PATH';

// Listing Folders

$foldersPath = array_diff(scandir($directoryPath), array('..', '.'));

// Reading the files of each folder

foreach($foldersPath as $folderPath){
    $folderPath = $directoryPath.$folderPath."\\";

    // check if the directory exist
    if(is_dir($folderPath)){
        if($folder = opendir($folderPath)){
            while(($fileName = readdir($folder)) !== false){
                if($fileName === '.' || $fileName === '..'){
                    continue;
                }

                $filePath = $folderPath.$fileName;

                // Reading the contents from the file
                $content = file_get_contents($filePath);


            }
        }

    }   
}
```